# High GPU usage by "System" process; high CPU usage by .NET ROS, major spikes

Tags: cpu, performance, freeze, gpu, lag

For the past few days, my PC has been getting random spikes of extremely high CPU and GPU usage (not at the same time), both of which cause lag and a .5-2 second freeze of the whole PC. I don't recall installing any new software or making any updates, also ran a full scan with Kaspersky to find nothing dangerous. What could be the cause? Also, one of my GPU fans has been rattling a little lately, but I highly doubt that's correlated in any way, considering GPU temps have been normal.

task manager with processes during a GPU spike, with above average CPU usage:

[image: task manager with processes during a GPU spike, with above average CPU usage]

GPU usage in one minute:

[image: GPU usage in one minute]

CPU usage in a minute:

[image: CPU usage in a minute]

Comment: Does [.NET Runtime Optimization Service High CPU Usage in Windows 11/10](https://www.windowsdigitals.com/net-runtime-optimization-service-high-cpu/) answer your question?

Comment: no, since the larger issue here is the System process using GPU memory.